# Change array keys and output lowest value by key

Tags: php

An odd one, I want to output the key of an array rather than the value and output the key by the lowest value.

My key change happens here:
`$totalAverages[$fullName] = $totalAverage;`

I am outputting the array out like so

```
foreach ($totalAverages as $key => $value) {
echo $key . $value;
}
```

The output to this is:

```
DAVE COWAN2.875GRAEME STRACHAN3JILL EMMORY2JOHN GREEN3.75SILVANA MARTIN2.752
```

So what I want to do is ind the lowest value and show the name/key only. So in this case it would be `JILL EMMORY2` because her key value is the lowest. This is data being selected from a table so it will be different all the time.

Comment: How does that code generate this output?

Comment: @VishnuJ asin where is it getting the names and values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) to get the minimum value from `$totalAverages` array.
- Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the corresponding key of *that* minimum value.

  ```
  $minTotalAverage = min($totalAverages);
  $fullname = array_search($minTotalAverage, $totalAverages);
  ```

Comment: That is a very clean method and is working perfectly.